# In Spring Data Redis, can the keyspace be dynamic?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-redis

I know that a `@RedisHash` aggregate root object can use a custom keyspace via a property on the `@RedisHash` annotation. My question is, how can I dynamically define the keyspace for a class of objects stored in Redis (via a Redis repository interface)?

For example, given the following root aggregate:

```java
@RedisHash /*("people")*/
public class Person {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @TimeToLive(unit = TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    private Long ttlMinutes = 60L;

    private String accountID;

    private String name;

}
```

I'd like to have the keyspace be based on not only a logical group (eg, `"people"`) but also on the `accountID`. For example, for a `Person` with id `e33bebb5-5fe2-47b8-8bb8-ef80950090e7` and `accountID` of `1234`, I'd want the key to look like `people:1234:e33bebb5-5fe2-47b8-8bb8-ef80950090e7`.

On a whim, I tried annotating a *method* with `@KeySpace` but that didn't work.

How can I accomplish this while using a Spring Data repository? Do I have to use `RedisTemplate` directly to gain this kind of flexibility?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize keyspaces using KeyspaceConfiguration as below.

```
  public static class MyKeyspaceConfiguration extends KeyspaceConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected Iterable<KeyspaceSettings> initialConfiguration() {
      return Collections.singleton(new KeyspaceSettings(Person.class, "people"));
    }
  }
```

As the key is a class name, it appears as if you cannot use different keyspaces for the same type (Person in your case).